# Magento2 get Random Order category collection

Tags: magento2, category

i want to **random 5 category** but not luck for me

i have use below code

```
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(5)->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

**Note: order random not working for me**

Comment: Your requirement is something like every page refresh 5 category random display?

Comment: no i want to get custom page in random 5 category get

Comment: Sorry. But, your question and last comment don't match. Can you please elaborate more in question?

Comment: @RohanHapani i want to get random 5 category in homepage  you got it ?

Comment: @RakeshDonda please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not proper solution. But, It maybe helpful for you. Try to use this below code :

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
    $categories = $categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $cat_arr = $categories->getData();
    $random_keys = array_rand($cat_arr, 5);
    $cat_ids = [];
    foreach ($random_keys as $key => $value) {
        $cat_ids[] = $cat_arr[$value]['entity_id'];
    }
    $cat_rand_obj = $categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $cat_ids]);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($cat_rand_obj->getData());
```

***Note: Avoid to use object manager. Use Factory Method structure.***

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Okay. If it's working then, please mark as accept and upvote. So, It will helpful for others.